# For Loop Creation of new instance of Array in ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, dynamic, for-loop, instance

Is there any way to create instances of array in a for loop?

Here's my code...

```
var recArrCon1:Array = new Array(50);
var recArrCon2:Array = new Array(50);
var recArrCon3:Array = new Array(50);
var recArrCon4:Array = new Array(50);
var recArrCon5:Array = new Array(50);
var recArrCon6:Array = new Array(50);
var recArrCon7:Array = new Array(50);
var recArrCon8:Array = new Array(50);
```

I want to make declaration in a dynamic way by a for loop.
Thanks in advance.

By the way, I'm using AS3

**Edit: The answer is (from Barış Uşaklı):**

```
var recArrCons:Object = {};
for(var i:int=1; i<=8; i++) 
{
    recArrCons["recArrCon" + i] = new Array(50);
}

trace(recArrCons.recArrCon4); // 4th array
```

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the class containing this code dynamic then you can create the names dynamically.

```
for(var i:int=1; i<=8; i++) 
{
    this["recArrCon" + i] = new Array(50);
}

trace(this.recArrCon4); // 4th array
```

Or you can store them in an `Object` like :

```
var recArrCons:Object = {};
for(var i:int=1; i<=8; i++) 
{
    recArrCons["recArrCon" + i] = new Array(50);
}

trace(recArrCons.recArrCon4); // 4th array
```

Comment: Edited my answer, it will only work if the containing class is `dynamic`

Comment: Thank you sir... This is the best and cleanest way I can derive new instances of Array bu storing it to an Object. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sir, how about accessing each object.. I'm trying to insert value on those arrays with dynamic variable String added in name like this...

var firstPName:String = "2"; 
for(var i:int=1; i <= 50; i++){
  if(!this["recArrCons.recArrCon"+firstPName][i]){
 this["recArrCons.recArrCon"+firstPName][i] = secondPName;
 break;
  }
}

It receives error on runtime. Though, I can access the values by directly calling them according to their names without "this[]".

Comment: `recArrCons['recArrCon'+ firstPName][i]` will give the `ith` element. It will be much more readable if you store a reference to the array though like : `var arr:Array = recArrCons['recArrCon'+firstPName]` and ten `arr[i]`

Comment: okay sir.. thanks alot. I now understand it that way...
recArrCons['recArrCon'+ firstPName][i] ... I'll try this first.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create instances of Array the way you are, it's very messy. I suggest using a list of arrays like this:

```
var arrays:Vector.<Array> = new <Array>[];
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   arrays.push(new Array(50));
}
```

Where you would access an array like this:

```
var inner:Array = arrays[2];
```

And values of the arrays using `[x][y]`:

```
trace(arrays[0][0]);
```

Comment: it's a 2 dimensional array. I have think this way too. But, base on the need of my application, it may cause some problem.

By the way Sir Marty. Thank you for response with my question. I'll get to use it someday.

Comment: @flashMark Sounds fair, just be cautious of polluting the current scope with a bunch of arrays.